# <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to Android development. I'm trying to create a splash screen for my first app using an XML file. However, it's giving me the following error message:

```
Rendering Problems Couldn't resolve resource @color/blue  Failed to convert @color/blue into a drawable (Details)  <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

I've looked all over the place to try to find out how to get drawables to work, but can't find much.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/blue"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a custom drawable file, and add  tag and apply your color to  tag. then this give the this newly created drawable path to android:drawable.

drawable/bg_bule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
</shape>
```

then put in your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/bg_bule"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</item>

</layer-list>
```